# EXCEL: Write "Good" or "Not Good" if cells values is outside of +/- .001

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, vba

I put a picture in that hopefully explains my situation better, thank you for all the help so far. I have learned alot.

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgJFc.jpg)

Comment: how about IF numbers in cells S5 thru S35 are bigger OR smaller than .001 then write good or not good

Comment: `if(a1<.001,"not good",if(a1>.001,"good","")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(S5:S35,">-.001",S5:S25,"<.001")<>COUNT(S5:S25),"NOT GOOD","GOOD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell U5:
`=if(ABS(max(S5:S35) - min(S5:S35))) < .001 then "Good" else "Not Good"`